# How to 'open file with' electron.js app?

Tags: javascript, windows, macos, file, electron

If the user right-clicks on a txt file he should me able to choose my app and the app should open the file.

My question is, how do I identify if the user has opened the app with a file and where is the file stored in the app?

In java, external parameters are stored in args[], does Electron have something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the parameters by

```
electron main.js argv1 argv2
```

and then access the parameters by

```
const = require('electron').remote;
console.log(remote.process.argv);
```

and the output will be `["argv1", "argv2"]`